# dataItems array how to display in view like JSON

Tags: angular, autocomplete, nativescript

I have a question about my code.

From this code I show in console this array:

```
 public country: Country[] = [];
  public _items: TokenModel[] = [];
   @ViewChild("autocomplete") autocomplete: RadAutoCompleteTextViewComponent;

   ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getallcountry();
    }
    getallcountry() {
        this.ws.getAllCountryws().subscribe(
            country => {
                this.country = country;
                const mycountry = country;
                console.log('mycountry', mycountry) // show correct JSON
                 for (let i = 0; i < mycountry.length; i++) {
                console.log(mycountry.length) // show correct
                     this._items.push(new TokenModel(mycountry[i].company_id, null));
                }
            },
            err => console.error('err', err),
            () => console.log('error')
        );
    }
get dataItems(): TokenModel[] {
    console.log('this._items', this._items)
    return this._items;
}
```

Show in console:

```
JS: this._items [Afghanistan, Albania, Algeria, American Samoa, Andorra, Angola, Anguilla, Antarctica, Antigua and Barbuda, Argentina, Armenia, Aruba, Australia, Austria, Azerbaijan, Bahamas, Bahrain, Bangladesh, Barbados, Belarus, Belgium, Belize, Benin, Bermuda, Bhutan, Bolivia, Bonaire, Bosnia and Herzegovina, Botswana, Bouvet Island, Brazil, British Indian Ocean Territory, Brunei Darussalam, Bulgaria, Burkina Faso, Burundi, Cambodia, Cameroon, Canada, Cape Verde, Cayman Islands, Central African Republic, Chad, Chile, China, Christmas Island, Cocos (Keeling) Islands, Colombia, Comoros, Congo, Democratic Republic of the Congo, Cook Islands, Costa Rica, Croatia, Cuba, CuraÃ§ao, Cyprus, Czech Republic, Cote d'Ivoire, Denmark, Djibouti, Dominica, Dominican Republic, Ecuador, Egypt, El Salvador, Equatorial Guinea, Eritrea, Estonia, Ethiopia, Falkland Islands (Malvinas), Faroe Islands, Fiji, Finland, France, French Guiana, French Polynesia, French Southern Territories, Gabon, Gambia, Georgia, Germany, Ghana, Gibra...
```

From html I want to display in autocomplete and write this code:

```
<RadAutoCompleteTextView #autocomplete [items]="dataItems" suggestMode="Suggest"
                displayMode="Tokens" row="1" col='0' hint="Country">
                <SuggestionView tkAutoCompleteSuggestionView>
                    <ng-template tkSuggestionItemTemplate let-country="item">
                        <StackLayout orientation="vertical" padding="10">
                            <Label [text]="text"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ng-template>
                </SuggestionView>
            </RadAutoCompleteTextView>
```

In view dosen't show nothing. I think that the problem is because result is in array, not in JSON.

Can you suggest me any idea how to show in view country?

Comment: Please share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=r7ajmr

Comment: or https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=J4caDm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using default TokenModel where the only valid attributes are `text` and `image`. But you are trying to bind `name` in your template which will be undefined.

Also it looks like you must use an ObservableArray in SuggestionView.

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=r7ajmr&v=2)

Answer (score 0):

You should use Observables for that here is updated code

```
    public _items: ObservableArray<TokenModel>;

constructor(private service: ItemService) {
    this.getallcountry();
}

ngOnInit(): void {

}
getallcountry() {
    this._items = new ObservableArray<TokenModel>();
    let countries = this.service.getItems();
    for (let i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
        this._items.push(new TokenModel(countries[i].name, undefined));
    }
}
get dataItems(): ObservableArray<TokenModel> {
    //console.log('this._items', this._items)
    return this._items;
}
```

Also in your html

```
<StackLayout backgroundColor="#66cdaa" padding="5">
<Label text="Select country"></Label>
<RadAutoCompleteTextView [items]="dataItems" suggestMode="Suggest"
    displayMode="Tokens">
    <SuggestionView tkAutoCompleteSuggestionView>
        <ng-template tkSuggestionItemTemplate let-item="item">
            <StackLayout orientation="vertical" padding="10">
                <Label [text]="item.text"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </ng-template>
    </SuggestionView>
</RadAutoCompleteTextView>
```

This should work.